# Solving the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{e^x-2^x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is there a way to solve this integral explicitly. I have never seen a solution before

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{e^x-2^x}dx$$

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{x (-1+\ln 2)}} dx$  use $\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k$ and integrate term by term

Comment: You can use the trick above to express the integral as an infinite sum, however that sum is not easy to evaluate. I tried evaluating the integral using Mathematica and it could not solve it (this does not exclude a closed form solution though).

Comment: How did you get the original integral into the form ∞1e−x1−ex(−1+ln2)dx

Comment: Try using $2^x = e^{\log(2)x}$

Comment: @Winther  : yes $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-(1+k(1-\ln 2))}}{1+k(1-\ln 2)}$  and this should be a [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) or hypergeometric series

Comment: @user1952009 Sure. With closed form I assumed OP meant in elementary functions - that I doubt exists.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may expand the integrand and integrate termwise as follows
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{- (1-\ln 2)x}} dx&=\int_1^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty {e^{-(n(1-\ln 2)+1)x}} dx
\\\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_1^\infty {e^{-(n(1-\ln 2)+1)x}} dx
\\\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-(n-\ln 2)}}{n-\ln 2}
\\\\&=\frac2e \psi\left(e^{-1},1,1-\ln 2\right)
\end{align}
$$ where $\psi$ is a special function: [the Lerch transcendent](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.14).

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{x (-1+\ln 2)}} dx$

Let $t=exp(-x)$. Then, the above is

$\displaystyle\int_0^{1/e} \frac{1}{1-t^{1-\ln 2}} dt$
.

Let $c = 1-\ln 2>0$. To find this integral, we have

$\displaystyle\int_0^{1/e} \frac{1}{1-t^c} dt = \displaystyle\int_0^{1/e} \sum_{i=0}^\infty t^{ic} dt = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \int_0^{1/e}  t^{ic} dt =  \sum_{i=0}^\infty \int_0^{1/e}  t^{ic} dt = \sum_{i=0}^\infty   \frac{e^{-ic-1}}{ic+1}$.

(Note that the sum and integral could be interchanged, since the conditions of dominated convergence theorem apply. The upper bound on the limit is less than 1. )